# Setting Colors for Plotly R "add_markers" layer

Tags: plotly

I'm wondering if anybody can help me set the colors manually for the "add_markers" layer of my plot.

```
df = data.frame("ID" = as.character(seq(1:10)),
                "DAY_START" = rep(0, times = 10),
                "DAY_END" = rep(10, times = 10),
                "EVENT" = factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 9)))

p_plot <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_segments(data = df, showlegend = FALSE,
               y=~ID, yend=~ID, x = ~DAY_START, xend = ~DAY_END,
               line=list(color = "blue", width = 3))
               

p_plot <- p_plot %>%
  add_markers(data = df, showlegend = T,
              y=~ID, yend=~ID, x = ~DAY_START, xend = ~DAY_END, color = ~EVENT,
              colors = c("red", "black", "turquoise", "magenta", "green"),
              marker = list(symbol = "circle", size = 7, line = list(color = "black", width = 1)))
```

[Wrong Dot Colors; I wanted "red", "black", "turquoise", "magenta", and "green"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSJrl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add markers within a trace, setting `colors` to a vector of colors:

```
fill_colors = c("red", "black", "turquoise", "magenta", "green", "orange")
plot_ly(data=df, y=~ID, x=~DAY_START) %>% 
  add_trace(color=~EVENT,mode = "markers", type="scatter",colors = fill_colors,
            marker=list(size=10,line=list(color="black"))) %>% 
  add_segments(showlegend=F,yend=~ID,xend=~DAY_END,line=list(color="blue"))
```

[image: mrkers]

Comment: Thank you! For my project, I need to have the "add_markers/add_trace()" command come after "add_segments" (and it is within an "If" statement, so it is not always used). I tried reversing the order in your code (add_segments then add_trace) and it didn't work anymore.